# How to handle user stopping a FitNesse test (slim table)

Tags: .net, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim, fitsharp

I have a custom table fixture (targeting SLIM) that handles the input table via;

```
public List<object> DoTable(List<List<String>> table)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to handle the user pressing the [Stop Test] button on the FitNesse test page so I can dispose of the resources my test has gracefully.

Perhaps there is another method that the slim runner finds dynamically for this.

Tests are being run thru FitSharp

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the test commands are sent in batch to the fixture and there is no 'stop' event/command being sent to the fixture when the tests are stopped.

I've mainly used it with the [SLiM](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.SlimProtocol) protocol not FIT but I can't see any reference to a command like that in either of them.

Comment: That's what I feared... seemingly no way to intercept that event.  Do you know if the .net SLiM runner respects IDisposable if not maybe I need to use a finalizer (uhggg)

Comment: sorry, haven't used the .net runner